# Architecting a collectable card game

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, playing-cards

I'm trying to learn how to program a (virtual) Trading Card Game game (similar to Magic the Gathering) in Javascript. I've read a little about MVC architecture and controllers, but it's all over my head (I don't have any formal CS education) and I'm wondering if anyone has any good links or tips about how I might learn more about code architecture at a beginner's level.

Would each "card" be represented as an object, and all the logic of the cards' rules be wrapped inside one large game engine function, or many small functions that are connected to each other?

Here's an example question:
Imagine there's a card which says, "When this card comes into play, draw a card." How should I architect the game to prepare for this situation, and how is it triggered (most efficiently)? Does the card trigger the game engine, or does the game engine parse each card that's played?

Here's another example: 
Imagine there's a card which says, "All your cards cost 1 less to play." and it stays in play permanently. How does the game understand that it needs to alter its rules in this case? Is this a function which listens for card to be played and interrupts the cost? As each turn resolves, where is this rule stored? Are there variables which store the base rules of the game (global card cost modifier: 0; your card cost modifier: 0) and other variables which store those new rules which cards introduce (your card cost modifier: -1), or are these variables dynamically created by the game engine as cards alter the rules (your elf cost modifier: -2)? And how do the rules know to change when a card has been destroyed, thus removing the card's rule modification?

Is what I need a primer on listeners and events? (I don't really know anything about them, but I've seen references to them from time to time.) Could you point me in the direction of a good resource?

To be clear, I'm not trying to make a long-winded request for folks to manually Google for me; I'm blindly fumbling in the dark and asking if someone would point me to the right words or phrases to search. Thank you!

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this post, as it deals more with general software design

Comment: there is this book New perspective Javascript and Ajax by patrick carey there is a very good tutorial on different card games using javascsript

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice blog about recreating a similar card game: Hearthstone from Blizzard. Allthough it is written in C# and uses Unity as a view layer, you get a pretty good understanding of how one goes about creating a suitable architecture for such a game. A fair warning though, recreating Magic the Gathering in Javascript can prove incredibly complicated and mess with your head a lot (I have first hand experience).

Blog: http://theliquidfire.com/2017/08/21/make-a-ccg-intro/

Comment: Not sure de-zombifying a seven-year old question is worth it, plus link-only answers aren’t really answers.

Comment: I was googling the exact same question Adam asked, today. MTG is still around so anybody could try building a MTG-like game anytime. I felt my answer was too long for a comment, hence the answer. I thougt Adam is looking for a starting point and provided one, if you think the answer could be improved I'd love to hear suggestions.

Comment: It could be not just a link; see the faq and various posts on meta for why link-only is bad. Thing is, though, that if it’s trivially searchable, it’s likely interested parties would... search. And find the same link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go a level deeper here and think about the "game" itself.  The game you're describing will actually be built around a "state machine" which is a core CS concept you should dive into and understand before you start building.

The rules of your game are going to be a state machine and the events (cards) triggered (by being played) during your game can modify those rules.  You'll want some kind of interpreter to "read" the card and to modify either the rules or the game state.  And then you'll need something to iterate the game through turns and phases, reading the state and taking appropriate action.

You'll also want to learn about stacks.  If your game lets players interrupt each other you'll need a way to keep track of which event should happen first because events will want to be able to affect, block, redirect other events.  A stack will help you keep track of that ordering.